# Styling, Absolute Divs

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that are the same, got the same html code,and styles.

Both divs are on position absolute.

Has anyone got an idea why are they different ?

When I change the position to relative they are equal.

The both, parent and sibiling is seted on position relative

[image]

Comment: Show your CSS! We can't help fix a styling issue without seeing the style. (And preferably HTML as well)

Comment: Please add html and css here for better understanding.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: You may find [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0?rq=1) useful for adding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes were different size beacuse absoulte div didn't had any width set on some sizes, and the width of it, depended on the text width in one row :/